# Xfinity router WiFi DNS not refreshed?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, domain-name, domain-name-system

I setup a new domain name. It's active and **working** from:

- Mobile Network
- Wired ethernet connection
- Other WiFi (not mine)
- using a VPN

It is **NOT** working from:

- Xfinity WiFi *without* a VPN

My Xfinity router will not allow me to change DNS to use a public DNS and is stuck using Xfinity's.

I have a workaround but would like to know why only on my Xfinity WiFi my DNS is not found?

Comment: How long since you setup the new domain name? Perhaps just waiting will clear things up? Did you power cycle the Xfinity router off and on?

Comment: It was created over 24 hours ago. I haven't done the power cycle. Might give it a shot.

Comment: Do you know what the TTL for the domain name might be? It usually defaults to something like 24 to 72 hours. So if it wasn’t changed to a lower value, that is how long it will take to propagate through the DNS system. Try lowering the TTL to 600 seconds (5 minutes) and see if that helps.

Comment: So am I to understand that Xfinity blocks ANY attempts to use a third-party DNS, even if you are connected to a VPN, which would then require all DNS queries be encrypted?  Have you specifically modified the DNS configuration of the Ethernet or Wireless adapter you are using?

Comment: @Ramhound that's what I have learned. The xFi router/modem is setup to use Comcast/Xfinity DNS. The admin console on the router won't allow you to change them. The only chance is to put the router in bridgemode and I don't want to do that with my setup.

Comment: @chonerman - If it works with a VPN, which you said it did work behind a VPN, not asking you to change anything on the modem just the Windows device. There are entire projects dedicated to solve this problem for less than $30. You can either set the DNS server on the device itself, or configure a DNS server on a device on the network, and point devices to that. Your ISP cannot block you from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

@Giacomo1968 suggestion to cycled the power worked after I waited around 4-5 days.

I did the soft reboot via Xfinity (ISP) and it didn't flush DNS like I hoped it would.

Pulling the power cable and waiting a minute did the trick. My DNS resolves now and I have no issue.